# The method "stopAircraftFollowing" is not providing a callback

Tags: dji-sdk

MSDK : 4.8.1

Platform: Android.

```
getActiveTrackOperator().stopAircraftFollowing(new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
            getActiveTrackOperator().switchMode(....);
        }
    });
```

I am using the following method to stop aircraft following before switching to a different mode. The "stopAircraftFollowing" method works as expected, but does not give a callback. Hence the "switchMode" method will not be called. I need to call the "switchMode" from the outside after giving a delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change in flight mode to detect when the stop operation has been completed.   Don't use a delay,  that is very unreliable.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. I was asking about switching between ActiveTrackModes like Profile, Trace and Spotlight. If aircraft is active in one of the modes, I need to stop it before switching to another. But the stopAircraftFollowing() is not giving a callback.

Comment: The change in flight mode does not provide any info if the state "ActiveTrackState.AIRCRAFT_FOLLOWING" is changed.